# <DefaultFormula> Tags not adding to the default formula of the column

Tags: xml, sharepoint

Hi 
I am currently creating a date time field for sharepoint in XML

My field is created but no default formula is added. Do i need another tag to say i want to have a defaultformula

. The schema i have is

```
<Field <!-- Some properties here-->>
<DefaultFormula>Today +182</DefaultFormula>
<FieldRefs>
</FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

Cheers 
          Truez

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<Field <!-- Some properties here-->>
    <DefaultFormula>=[Today]+182</DefaultFormula>
    <FieldRefs>
    </FieldRefs>
</Field>
```

I've found many helpful examples here:
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/examples-of-common-formulas-HA010105479.aspx?CTT=3

Comment: Some more example formulae here too: http://abstractspaces.wordpress.com/2009/05/02/common-date-time-formulas-for-sharepoint-calculated-fields/